# how to split a request message in camel for different destination?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

I have a request message in the format of lets say:

```
Class RequestMessage{
    private ClassA classA;
    private ClassB classB;
}
```

I want to split this request message in my orchestration service and want to send object `classA` as request to `dest1` and `classB` to `dest2` and then send the aggregated output to client. I am using Apache Camel. Mostly, all I could find was to split on XPath or something but couldn't get any help. One solution come to my mind was using multicast pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the splitter / aggregator pattern.

Otherwise, I would suggest using a multicast to send to two routes. In these routes change the bodies to `body.getClassA()` and `body.getClassB()` respectively. At the end of each route you could update the original body. This could be done by placing the original body into the headers prior to setting the body.

Comment: can you please help me with splitter pattern ? I can do that with multicast

Comment: So I have not used these before but I would suggest you use a Splitter with a custom splitter bean and then pass to a MessageRouter to choose the destination by payload type.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html   http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can break out these two items into two distinct request objects, something like RequestMessageA and RequestMessageB (probably with a base class or interface that they both extend say BaseRequestMessage). Then you could have a splitter in your route which splits your requests (e.g. if you had both requests in a List) and then routes each flavor to the desired destination.

In Spring DSL for example (pseudocode, not tested):

```
<split>
   <simple>${body}</simple>
   <choice>
      <when>
         <simple>${body} is RequestA</simple>
         <to uri="dest1"/>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <to uri="dest2"/>
      </otherwise>
   </choice>
</split>
```

Or something similar with a splitter using the [content based routing EIP](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html)?